# Google Chrome in launcher got replaced

Tags: 16.04, launcher, .desktop

Today, when I open google chrome from the unity launcher, it's getting stuck in opening homepage. It hangs for 3 seconds and the option to force quit immediately popup.

I tried opening through terminal, google-chrome-stable command, and it opens normally. I think my launcher icon got replaced. One thing I noticed was its not on the same position as last time. Its now on bottom of the list. Also when I hover on it, the launcher name is now my local IP (192.168.99.10) instead of Google Chrome - web Browser and it lost the option for Open a New Window and Open a Private Window when right clicking it. I suspected it got replaced and now loading my local environment, but I'm not sure why it hangs and cannot proceed.

So I searched my /usr/share/applications directory and find google-chrome.desktop, but upon checking it seems *normal*.

```
Exec=/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable %U
Terminal=false
Icon=google-chrome
Type=Application
Categories=Network;WebBrowser;
MimeType=text/html;text/xml;application/xhtml_xml;image/webp;x-scheme-handler/http;x-scheme-handler/https;x-scheme-handler/ftp;
Actions=new-window;new-private-window;
```

I'm not sure what has caused this and how to fix it. I don't want to run google chrome through terminal every time I needed it.

There wasn't any update and the only thing *different* that I did was running chrome with a flag from terminal last week once:

```
google-chrome --disable-web-security --user-data-dir="/tmp/chrome_tmp"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have solved this by deleting all *.desktop files found here
~/.local/share/applications